# Push notifications being sent but not received iOS - Cloud functions

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications to the iPhone 6s I am using for testing. I've followed through the Firebase documentation and I can't seem to get a notification arrive to the phone. When I try to send a test notification with the FCM token I get after registering, it is classed as "sent" on the firebase console but not "received".

The minimum software version for the app is iOS 13 so I haven't added the deprecated functions for the notification service.

I've tried:

- Disabling and reenabling the push notification and background task capabilities in xcode
- Created new certificates and provisioning profiles using the capabilities
- Uninstalling the app from the phone and reinstalling it
- Setting FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO and YES in the Info.plist file
- Writing and running the cloud function that will be used to send the notification which runs as "ok" according to the firebase console
- Cleaning the build folder
- Using all of the tokens that are returned on registering

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advance :)

App Delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    db = Firestore.firestore()

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        print("granted: (\(granted)")
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
        } else if let result = result {
            print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
        }
    }

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey: "backing_up")
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let email = user?.email
    let password = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "password")
    let setup = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "accountSetup")
    let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email ?? "", password: password ?? "")
    user?.reauthenticate(with: credential)
    if (user?.isEmailVerified ?? false) && setup {
        let homeVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = homeVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
        let loginVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = loginVC

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
    Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    print("token: \(token)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("failed to register for remote notifications with with error: \(error)")
}

// If in foreground
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)

    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
}

// If in background
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("handling notification")
    if let notification = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String:AnyObject] {
        let message = parseRemoteNotification(notification: notification)
        print(message as Any)
    }
    completionHandler()
}

private func parseRemoteNotification(notification:[String:AnyObject]) -> String? {
    if let identifier = notification["identifier"] as? String {
        return identifier
    }

    return nil
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
```

Comment: Are you sure app is using sandbox mode? And why don't you publish it on testflight and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I published it to testflight and my mate's phone, who's connected to testflight as a tester, didn't send the FCM token to the database so I'm assuming it had an issue registering for push notifications in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY! I tried to fix the issue by just starting from scratch and began creating another app. Halfway through the process, I found that I hadn't uploaded a .p8 file to Firebase for the app I was trying to get notifications to work for (I thought I had but apparently not).

If you have the same problem, check if your app is properly registered with Firebase on the console for cloud messaging!